# Can gRPC support `x-www-form-encoded` data?

Tags: go, grpc, http2

I am trying to accept a POST request from an external service, but the data is `x-www-form-encoded` data. Our system is gRPC, but we use [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) to pass json rest requests.

If I add to following to my `.proto` file

```
rpc Action(ActionRequest) returns (ActionResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
        post: "/v1/action"
        body: "*"
    };
}
```

Any messages I try and create will fail with

```
`invalid character 'p' looking for beginning of value - Error: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = invalid character 'p' looking for beginning of value`
```

This makes sense as 'p' is the first character of the `x-www-form-encoded` data (payload is the object name).

It would so far appear I don't have access to the raw request body, and it seems it may be possible with a custom marshaller that feels like overkill, and probably out of scope.

However I cannot for the life of me see how to access this data. I [have tried adding another proto from googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/httpbody.proto). However I have found the documentation for this aspect of gRPC difficult to follow and I may be doing it wrong.

Comment: Nope, but there's an open PR with a marshaller that would support it: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/pull/548/files

Comment: You said it yourself: grpc-gateway expects JSON. If you give it form encoded data (or anything other than JSON, really) it's going to complain.

Comment: More discussion: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/7

Comment: @maxm would I need to fork the runtime itself to use this proposed marshaller? Or can it be added 'in-place' somewhere? I am not very experienced with gRPC and golang yet.

Comment: Presumably you can just build from this fork: https://github.com/jinleileiking/grpc-gateway. But the code doesn't have any tests written against it and it's entirely unclear if it works.

Comment: Yea my problem is this is in a highly automated system, and for reasons that would be a lot of trouble. Is there any "simple" way to get at the raw request body? Even as a string or something? The solutions in the posted threads have led me no where (or didn't work in the system/beyond my current skill level).